# Launch specific app when external accessory attached

Tags: iphone, external-accessory

I've looked at the Apple docs on this and it seems after adding the correct protocol to the Info.plist from my understanding it should launch the corresponding app?

> Applications that are able to communicate with an external accessory should declare the ?protocols they support in their Info.plist file. Declaring support for specific protocols lets the system know that your application can be launched when that accessory is connected. If no application supports the connected accessory, the system may choose to launch the App Store and point out applications that do.

I've done this but nothing happens when I plug the accessory in. The app works great with the accessory otherwise.

I know this is possible, because I've seen other accessories that do it, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

to make the app launch at start,you should first RequestApplicationLaunch in your hardware.Pls refer to apple's MFi Accessory Firmware Specification R42 page 183.

Comment: This feature is listed in Apple's Accessory-Design-Guidelines part 21, App Launch

https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf