# Can't get Notification after connecting serial dock connector between iPhone and iMac

Tags: iphone, ios, external-accessory

Is it possible to connect iMac to iPhone through the dock connector ? Also I am using the EAAccessory framework but I am not get any notifications when I connect the serial cable to iPhone. If any one knows about this please give me a suggestion.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post the same question - you have now deleted the edits that were made to your original question to fix typos etc, and the comments asking for clarification have also been deleted - this is very rude.

Comment: Serial dock connector means Serial cable..

Comment: What do you mean by *serial* cable ? "Serial" is very vague. Are you talking about RS-232 or something ?

Comment: Ya and sorry paul but i have some problem for that account so i have to delete it...  now please give me any solution if you know about it.

Comment: You need to clarify the question first

Comment: No i am talking about normal dock-30 cable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3884/discussion-between-raj-and-paul-r)

Comment: So you mean the **USB** cable, not a "serial" cable ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3886/discussion-between-raj-and-paul-r)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a lot of confusion regarding EAAccessoryManager and the accompanying classes. These are only for use with MFI sanctioned hardware i.e. those manufacturers that have taken the time to follow the MFI program and integrate the requisite hardware into their device.

The use of a chip and the establishment of a protocol allows for the facilitation of a communication stream between the app and the device.

Sam is correct in his statement but there is no need to jailbreak your app in order to bypass the MFI program however, you will not be able to submit to the App Store if you follow the procedure I am about to briefly outine:

1. Obtain all of the header files for the IOKit [iOS OpenSource Browser](http://opensource.apple.com/source/)
2. Add them to your solution
3. Include the IOKit.h framework
4. Head to http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Interfacing/Cocoa#IOKit for an example of how to use IOKit and icotl commands to achieve what you require

I have successfully implemented IOKit operations on an iOS device so this is definitely possible as long as you are willing to forego submission to the App Store.

Comment: That sounds good, but why can't apps that used this be sold in the App Store?

Comment: OK I see--using the IOKit library isn't allowed by apple in App Store apps.

Answer (score 2):

Raj..

for get notification for connection accessory first of you have to register your accessory to MFI. otherwise you have to jailbreak your iPhone. for jail break check this code

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

static struct termios gOriginalTTYAttrs;

static int OpenSerialPort()
{
    int        fileDescriptor = -1;
    int        handshake;
    struct termios  options;

    // Open the serial port read/write, with no controlling terminal, and don't wait for a connection.
    // The O_NONBLOCK flag also causes subsequent I/O on the device to be non-blocking.
    // See open(2) ("man 2 open") for details.

    fileDescriptor = open("/dev/tty.iap", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fileDescriptor == -1)
    {
        printf("Error opening serial port %s - %s(%d).\n",
               "/dev/tty.iap", strerror(errno), errno);
        goto error;
    }

    // Note that open() follows POSIX semantics: multiple open() calls to the same file will succeed
    // unless the TIOCEXCL ioctl is issued. This will prevent additional opens except by root-owned
    // processes.
    // See tty(4) ("man 4 tty") and ioctl(2) ("man 2 ioctl") for details.

    if (ioctl(fileDescriptor, TIOCEXCL) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error setting TIOCEXCL on %s - %s(%d).\n",
            "/dev/tty.iap", strerror(errno), errno);
        goto error;
    }

    // Now that the device is open, clear the O_NONBLOCK flag so subsequent I/O will block.
    // See fcntl(2) ("man 2 fcntl") for details.

    if (fcntl(fileDescriptor, F_SETFL, 0) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error clearing O_NONBLOCK %s - %s(%d).\n",
            "/dev/tty.iap", strerror(errno), errno);
        goto error;
    }

    // Get the current options and save them so we can restore the default settings later.
    if (tcgetattr(fileDescriptor, &gOriginalTTYAttrs) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error getting tty attributes %s - %s(%d).\n",
            "/dev/tty.iap", strerror(errno), errno);
        goto error;
    }

    // The serial port attributes such as timeouts and baud rate are set by modifying the termios
    // structure and then calling tcsetattr() to cause the changes to take effect. Note that the
    // changes will not become effective without the tcsetattr() call.
    // See tcsetattr(4) ("man 4 tcsetattr") for details.

    options = gOriginalTTYAttrs;

    // Print the current input and output baud rates.
    // See tcsetattr(4) ("man 4 tcsetattr") for details.

    printf("Current input baud rate is %d\n", (int) cfgetispeed(&options));
    printf("Current output baud rate is %d\n", (int) cfgetospeed(&options));

    // Set raw input (non-canonical) mode, with reads blocking until either a single character 
    // has been received or a one second timeout expires.
    // See tcsetattr(4) ("man 4 tcsetattr") and termios(4) ("man 4 termios") for details.

    cfmakeraw(&options);
    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

    // The baud rate, word length, and handshake options can be set as follows:

    cfsetspeed(&options, B19200);    // Set 19200 baud    
    options.c_cflag |= (CS8);  // RTS flow control of input


    printf("Input baud rate changed to %d\n", (int) cfgetispeed(&options));
    printf("Output baud rate changed to %d\n", (int) cfgetospeed(&options));

    // Cause the new options to take effect immediately.
    if (tcsetattr(fileDescriptor, TCSANOW, &options) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error setting tty attributes %s - %s(%d).\n",
            "/dev/tty.iap", strerror(errno), errno);
        goto error;
    }    
    // Success
    return fileDescriptor;

    // Failure "/dev/tty.iap"
error:
    if (fileDescriptor != -1)
    {
        close(fileDescriptor);
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    char somechar[8];
    fd=OpenSerialPort(); // Open tty.iap with no hardware control, 8 bit, BLOCKING and at 19200 baud
    if(fd>-1)
    {
        write(fd,"*",1); // Write handshaking message over serial
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // After this, our device or our PC program should be strobing serial ground to gain access to the Iphone Serial Line
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        read(fd,&somechar[0],1); // Read 1 byte  over serial.  This will block (wait) untill the byte has been received
        if(somechar[0]=='*') // Check if this byte is a "handshaking" message
        {
            printf("Serial connection established!\n"); // If it is, we have established a connection to the device and can freely read/write over serial!
            while(1) // Do this forever or untill someone presses CTRL+C
            {
                read(fd,&somechar[0],1);  // Read a character over serial!
                putchar(somechar[0]); // Write the character to the Terminal!!
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your iPhone to an iMac and you have either iTunes or Xcode running, you would be able to see that the iPhone is connected.

In Xcode, go to the Organizer window.  In iTunes, look under the Devices in the left-hand column.

The EAAccessory framework, which I have not used, should have nothing to do with this.

Comment: hi thanks for giving answer, but i want to get notification in my iOS application when i connect the usb cable to my iPhone

Comment: I now understand.  Here's a sample:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I also chek that eademo application but in that application also i can't get any notification when i connect the USB cable between iPhone and iMac\

Comment: I believe that the EA framework requires the other side to talk with the code on the iOS device.  I don't know if EA was designed with a Mac as an accessory in mind.  I think they assume the the accessories are hardware devices that responded to EA queries.

Comment: Okay and thanks for wasting your valuable time for this question... :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3890/discussion-between-raj-and-mahboudz)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: [Launch specific app when external accessory attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975775/launch-specific-app-when-external-accessory-attached)  - not all accessories can signal to launch app when they are connected. I think that ordinal USB cable also can't.

About IOKit: You can add nesessary files from Xcode itself - open Xcode.app package. IOKit framework is located in Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks 
simply copy absent files (or make link) to

Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework

and to

Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework

and also for all simulator platforms

You should know that not all functions of IOKit can work on real device (but they work under simulator) due to iOS sandbox security.
But You can work with IORegistry well. My first project on iOS was implemetation of the IORegistryExplorer.
Good luck!