# Passing objects between different applications

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to develop a Bluetooth Fitness Watch (Bluetooth LE only) as a project of mine. I have created an application (for now we can call it FitX) that allows the user to connect to the watch, similar to the the Pebble Watch, and the object within this app is called fitXWatch (handles the connection and all of that).

However, I now wish to be able to reference this fitXWatch object in another test app so users would be able to integrate my watch into there respective apps. This is the same principal again as Pebble.

I know iOS in general is very sandboxed, but based on Pebble, it gives me hope it can be done.
So my question is this, How can I pass an object from one app to another app similar to Pebble?

Thanks!

Comment: @ElTomato No, I am saying that there is an iOS application known as "Pebble" that communicates with the Pebble Watch. From my understanding, in this app you connect to the Pebble watch. Then in your own application, you import the Pebble Framework and can reference the Pebble object from your own app that was created in the Pebble app

Comment: @ElTomato No Problemo!

Comment: @ElTomato: yes, you can send data from one app to another in iOS using network protocols.  Sandbox has nothing to do with this.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975775/launch-specific-app-when-external-accessory-attached) might be useful.

Comment: @Pranav Thanks for that but I do not think that it is what I'm talking about. I'm referring to APP A creating a singleton object of my watch. And I am talking about APP B being able to retrieve this created singleton object from APP A in order to communicate with the watch within APP B. Thanks!

Comment: Is APP B going to be launched by APP A or is it going to be launched by the user.

Comment: @Pranav Launched by the user after finishing everything in APP A. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's Technical [Q&A QA1657](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1657/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010232):

Q:  I understand that the External Accessory framework in iOS 3.0 and later will allow my application to communicate with Bluetooth devices. So why doesn't my application see the Bluetooth accessory sitting next to my iPhone?

A: The External Accessory framework is designed to allow iOS applications to communicate only with hardware accessories that are developed under Apple's MFi licensee program. MFi compliant accessories can be implemented as wired devices, meaning they plug in to the Apple device's 30-pin or Lightning connector, or as wireless devices, whereby they use Bluetooth as the communication channel. Either way, an application that uses the External Accessory framework will not be notified of an accessory's presence unless the accessory identifies itself as being MFi compliant, i.e., it was specifically designed to interface with an iOS application.

Comment: Thank you for this. If I understand correctly however, this is simply explaining why some Bluetooth devices are not shown with Settings --> Bluetooth ---> Search for Bluetooth devices. Correct? This is useful but I am not sure how it explains my question. Unless I misunderstood? Thank you regardless

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure you can't combine the two apps into one single app? Or, maybe convert APP A into a framework and include that framework in APP B?

There is no way to do what you ask locally. You will have to save your object to a file and then upload that file to a remote server. When APP B is opened, it should contact that server and download the file.

Comment: I think what I might be referring too is converting an APP into a framework. How is that done? Thanks

Comment: If you want a quick-fix solution, then you could include App A's Xcode project in App B. If you want a true static framework, take a look at [this](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework/blob/master/README.mdown). I am afraid I can't elaborate any more as I have never built a static framework.